# How to use portion of an array

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry if everyone sees me post a lot of silly questions today (just a preface). However this is the final for a summer class and my teacher stopped caring/explaining how to do things for my first coding class.

For this project I have to print a list of integers from a .dat file into a program in reverse order with a max of 40 possible values in the array (Did all that) The problem I am encountering is that he said the program should also be flexible enough to deal with less than 40 values. However given my current code I always encounter an error saying "nosuchelementexception". Any help would be greatly appreciate. Below is a copy of what I have:

```
import java.io.*;               //Imports any file operation (ie Reading or Writing)
import java.util.Scanner;       //Imports scanner class

public class program3
{
    public static void main(String [] ars) throws IOException
    {
        double [] Values;               // creating array called value
        Values = new double [40];       // establishing array with 40 cells
        int k;                  // creating counter integer

        Scanner InputFile = new Scanner( new FileReader("temp.dat"));       // input file you wish to open.

        for (k = 0 ; k < Values.length ; k++)

            Values[k] = InputFile.nextDouble();


        for (k = Values.length - 1 ; k >= 0 ; k--)

            System.out.println("Cell " + k + " contains the value " + Values[k]);

        InputFile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Values.length` will **always** be `40` regardless of how many elements are in the file. If there are 35 elements, attempting to read element 36 will be a problem.

Comment: It is a Java convention to not capitalize the first letter of variables, capitalization of the first character is for Objects and Classes. Notice how stackoverflow is highlighting your variable names

Comment: thank you for the advice, I will do my best to not continue to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the `length` attribute of an array refers to the *declared* length, not the amount of data in it.

When you try to use the length (in this case 40) to control the loop you use for reading data, you will get an error if there are fewer elements to read.

What you want to do is read more input only while there exists more input to get:

```
    int k = 0;
    while (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) {
        Values[k++] = inputFile.nextDouble();
    }
```

Also, consider using an `ArrayList` instead of an array.  The `ArrayList` class allows you to store a dynamic amount of data, so you don't have to worry about pre-allocating storage space:

```
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) {
        values.add(inputFile.nextDouble());
    }
```

Comment: The `println()` loop also needs to account for the number of doubles actually read.

Comment: The existing print loop would merely have to loop based off `values.size()` instead an external counter.

Comment: Ehm the array has size 40 and you start storing at index 1. What If you actually read 40 numbers?

Comment: Thank you so much, as well as everyone else who answered. I used this as well as adding an if statement into the 2nd listen for statement:
    if (value[k] == 0)
        System.out.println("");
This in turn got rid of any original printlns that had 0 due to the lack of values in the imported .dat file

Comment: @xgeorgekx `k++` is a post-increment operator, so indexing of the array will start at `0`.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop and a counter

```
import java.io.*;               // Imports any file operation (ie Reading or Writing)
import java.util.Scanner;       // Imports scanner class

public class program3
{
    public static void main(String [] ars) throws IOException
    {
        double [] Values;               // creating array called Values
        Values = new double [40];       // establishing array has 40 cells
        int counter = 0;                  // creating counter integer

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner( new FileReader("temp.dat"));       //input file you with to open.

        while(inputFile.hasNextDouble()){

            Values[counter] = InputFile.nextDouble();
            counter++;

        }
        for (i = counter - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)

            System.out.println("Cell " + i + " contains the value " + Values[i]);

        InputFile.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to use an Array, use an `ArrayList<Double>`. This allows you to call `values.add(value)` to add to the list. The length is variable and you can use your same code (just replace `values[i]` with `values.get(i)`)

However, if you do have to use arrays, created a method that adds to the array. Start with a 0 length array, and when an element is added, create a new array of length+1, then copy the old elements in, and add the new element at the end.

There are many other ways to go about this, but these two allow you to use your existing working code.

Array approach:

```
values = new double[0];

public void add(double x){
    double[] temp = new double[values.length +1];
    for(int i =0; i< values.lenght; i++){
        temp[i] = values[i];
    }
    temp[temp.length-1] = x;
    values = temp;
}
```

Comment: this is like basic of the basic right now. We just covered arrays and have not explored anything like ArrayLists yet. So unfortunately I cant >.< thank you though

Comment: Added explanation for using arrays.

Comment: The missing link here is that the code needs to know when to stop reading values from the file. If that were solved then an array would work too.

Comment: So if i were to input in the first for loop something along the lines of:
if (k > values[k])
 break;
?

Comment: generally when reading a file you use a while loop and continue while something hasNext()

Comment: `while(values.length<=40){
...
}`

Comment: Your `println()` loop also needs to know how many doubles were read from the file, to know where to start working backwards from.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an arrayList instead so you don't have to initially set the size of the array. This would make it so that you never have empty elements in the array.

Another option would be to initialize the array with placeholder values like -1, and then only perform the switch if the value is not -1.

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter that keeps track of how many item you put into the array and use that to determine where to stop when you go to print them out.

Answer (score 0):

Is there 40 elements in your .dat file. If there isnt your code probably gave the exception.

```
for (k = 0 ; k < Values.length ; k++)
Values[k] = InputFile.nextDouble();
```

If your .dat file doesn't contain 40 elemennts then value[39] can't be filled in.

Answer (score 0):

An Array has a fixed size after initialising it, so you may want to use dynamic datastructure or instead use a while loop as posted below. I personally would recommend an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) in this case.

You should also use the method

> Scanner.hasNext() or in your particular case Scanner.hasNextDouble() [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble())

to get any new elements.

So your program would then look like this:

```
import java.io.*;               //Imports any file operation (ie Reading or Writing)
import java.util.Scanner;       //Imports scanner class
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class program3
{
    public static void main(String [] ars) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();

        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner( new FileReader("temp.dat"));

        while (inputFile.hasNextDouble()) {
               doubles.add(inputFile.nextDouble());
        }

        inputFile.close();


        for (Double value : doubles) {
             System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Java has convenient methods in it's Collections class to allow sorting. You may want to check this out if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I admire your grit getting on Stack Overflow.
To reward you here's your answer.

The first for loop you have iterates over your new, empty array. That would be find except you are RETRIEVING information from the Scanner object, `InputFile`.

So you should in fact be iterating over that object! Not your array. No shame though. Classic mistake.

Here's my version of your code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException; //Imports any file operation (ie Reading or Writing)
import java.util.Scanner; //Imports scanner class

public class program3
{
    public static void main( String [] ars ) throws IOException
    {
        double [] Values; // creating array called value
        Values = new double [40]; // establishing array has 20 cells
        int k; // creating counter integer

        //input file you with to open.
        Scanner InputFile = new Scanner( new FileReader( "temp.dat" ) ); 

        for ( k = 0; InputFile.hasNextDouble(); k ++ )

            Values[k] = InputFile.nextDouble();


        for ( k = Values.length - 1; k >= 0; k-- )

            System.out.println( "Cell " + k + " contains the value " + Values[k] );

        InputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You still print from index 39 even if the array contains less

Comment: Ah. I didn't realize that wasn't the requirement. I figured the existence of the max of 40 cells would be evident this way. Wherein the iteration the value 0 actually prints.